# c++ parsing comments using string buffer

Tags: c++, string, parsing, newline

I am trying to write a code that will read in c++ files, recognize comments, and store each words in comment into a vector. My problem is that I cannot find a way to read in a single line comment.

My logic is this: If the first character in a string buffer is '/' check for second char to determine whether it is a single line or multi-line comments. If the comment is single line, read in every word delimited by whitespace until I hit new line character '\n'. If the comment is multi-line, I will read in every word until I hit another */. so the code snippet for this is,

```
    while(!input.eof())
    {

        string buffer;

        input >> buffer;

        //check if the line is comment
        if(buffer[0] == '/')
        {
            //single line comment
            if(buffer[1] == '/')
            {
              //read in until I hit newlineChar, and store all words into vector
                while(buffer[0] != '\n')
                {
                    input >> buffer;
                    vector.add(buffer);
                }
            }

            //multiline comment
            else if(buffer[1] == '*')
            {
                //read until I hit */ and store all words into vector
                while(buffer[buffer.size()-1] != '*' && buffer[buffer.size()] != '/')
                {
                        input >> buffer;
                        vector.add(buffer);
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

The Problem is with my understanding of new line character. I don't quite understand how string processes the new line char. I'm assuming the string treats new line char as another delimiter just like whitespace. But even in such case, there has to be a way to recognize end of a line using string. What could be a solution to this? Any input is appreciated.

EDIT: Taking advice of user4581301, I added the while loop that reads till the end of file. And to note the problem of lines having extraction operator followed by // like

```
std::cout<<"//this is not a comment.";
```

And one way I can think of to avoid this is to read in entire line using getline and char*.

```
char buffer[200];
input.getline(buffer,200);
string tempStr = buffer;
vector.add(tempStr);
```

In this case, how can I break individual string stored in vector into words?

Comment: Need to see how you are reading in the string to give a reasionable answer. `input >> buffer;`, for example, discards all whitespace **including the newlines**. Off topic: This is a non-trivial program no matter how much instructors seem to think otherwise and assign it to new programmers. For example, `std::cout << "//Ha ha ha! Screw you!";`. You have to track a lot more than just '/' and '*'.

Comment: Thank you! That is something I did not take into account. But in the case presented above, since the file's first string is "//Ha, wouldn't the parser logic ignore the "?

Comment: You have me there, but I add a space, `std::cout << " //Ha ha ha! Screw you!";`, and the code will detect false positive. Consider also that `i++;//increment i` will miss a valid comment.

Comment: I see! For detecting a line of comment, I need to have method of recognizing a new line character. For detecting comments behind code without whitespace, I need to use forloop to see if a string has ; in it and return the counter on that value. Then, from counter+1, I need make a substring of the entire string to see if it is a comment.

For the first part though, do you think using new line char to determine a single line of comment is a valid method?

Thank you again!

Comment: For a single line comment yes. Look into `std::getline` to read the file line-by-line. If the string is a whole line, you know exactly where the line ended; the string ended there as well. I think this may be a better solution than operating on a word-by-word basis. It will catch `//` that is not preceded by a space, for one thing. To catch the trickier cases like comments in strings, you will probably need a state machine or a regex.

Comment: Not really about your problem but important anyway: you always have to check **after** reading whether the read attempt was successful. For example: `while (input >> buffer) { ... }`